# How to suppress all checks for a file in Checkstyle?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm doing an override for a third party class and I want to suppress all checks for it (since I'm only keeping it around until the patch is accepted).

Is there a way to suppress all checks for a file?

I tried using "*" but that fails.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Don't know whether you're using command line or in an IDE, but you'll basically need a suppresions file. If you're manually editing the Checkstyle config file, add a new module to it:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="mysuppressions.xml" />
</module>
```

Your `mysuppression.xml` can be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files="TheClassToIgnore\.java" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
</suppressions>
```

The value for "`files`" attribute is basically a regex for your source files, and the value for the "`checks`" attribute is regex for what checks to skip ("`[a-zA-Z0-9]*`" basically means skip everything). This is the pattern you're looking for I guess?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. But it didn't work. Do I have to set a checkstyle configuration somewhere to use the 'files' and 'checks' attributes as regular expressions? I can see that in the already existant suppres tags doesn't use the 'file' attribute as regex: i.e. files="MyClass.java" and not files="MyClass\.java".

Comment: Hmm... are you using an IDE? I'm afraid I can't help you more because the above is basically a simplified version of what I've set up for my current work - basically there was a group of similarly-named generated classes that we want Checkstyle to ignore, so we ignored a particularly pattern in the name.

Comment: Doesn't help me. Don't have access to the server and the architects aren't likely to give it. Was hoping for something like @SupressWarnings("com.puppycrawl.tools.*")

Comment: To skip all checks in all files under directories (packages) named "generated", you must use regex pattern 
`<suppress checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*" files="[\\/]generated[\\/]" />`  
It was really little hard for me to find out the right pattern for **files** parameter.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` seems excessive, why don' you just use `.*`?

Comment: How can I add multiple specific checks into the `checks="..."` parameter? How are they separated?

Comment: Try making the path to the mysuppressions.xml file from the project root . ... ie ... ./codequality/mysuppressions.xml

Comment: i'm getting file is not found. it is placed right at the rool of "modules" folder, nearby checkstyle.xml.

Answer (score 33):

I was able to suppress the checks in a file by adding the SuppressionCommentFilter tag in my checks.xml:

First, I added the FileContentHolder tag as a child of TreeWalker tag (this step is *not* needed since version 8.1 of com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle):

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
    ...
    <module name="FileContentsHolder"/>
    ...
</module>
```

Then I added the SuppressionCommentFilter in the checks.xml (since version 8.1 of com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle - under "TreeWalker" node):

```
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
```

In each file that I wanted to suppress the checks I inserted the following comment in the first line of the file:

```
// CHECKSTYLE:OFF
```

Comment: Henrique, note that `FileContentsHolder` should be under `TreeWalker` while `SuppressionCommentFilter` should be under `Checker`.
If you put them both under `TreeWalker` or both under `Checker` - this would not work.

For more information, see http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionCommentFilter

Comment: Since this tripped me up just now -- @MatanRubin's comment is accurate for versions of checkstyle up to 8.0. However, checkstyle 8.1 and 8.2 made some backwards-incompatible changes: the correct thing to do now is to have `SuppressionCommentFilter` be under `TreeWalker`. The `FileContentsHolder` module seems to have been removed entirely -- it's no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Michael0x2a

Answer (score 21):

aberrant80's answer helped a lot. With the help of his hint - using regex pattern matching, I was also able to suppress checkstyle for an entire package by adding this to the checkstyle-suppressions.xml file.
For eg. to skip checkstyle checks on all auto generated java files under the jaxb package,

```
    <suppressions>
        <suppress checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*" files="[\\/]jaxb[\\/]" />
    </suppressions>
```

Comment: You can just use `.*` for `checks` and `/jaxb/` for `files` if your path separator character is `/`.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the Checkclipse Eclipse plugin for Checkstyle, you can include or exclude file patterns (including directories) by going to the Checkclipse > File Filter tab under project properties. For example, my project contains **src** and **test** directories at the top level. I want Checkstyle applied to only files in the **src** directory (omitting **test**), so I added an include pattern that looks like this:

```
src/.+java$
```

As you can see, it uses a regex-style syntax for pattern specification.

Comment: In the current version of the plugin, you must first de-select "Use simple configuration" before you can reach the configurable file sets.

Comment: That comment should be added to this answer. +1 anyway to both.

Answer (score 3):

@aberrant80's answer is very inspiring although it didn't work in my project. In order to suppress any warnings that checkstyle looks for in Foo.java, according to [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html), if maven is used:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
        <configuration>
            ...
            <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
            ...
        </configuration>                
    ...
</plugin>
```

And in *checkstyle-suppressions.xml*

```
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <suppress files="Foo.java" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*" />
</suppressions>
```

So far the highest version is 1.1 (1.2 does not exist).

Comment: value of 'files' attr is regexp too.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to ignore write protected files. Or files in a package.

Comment: I use checkstyle through Eclipse. There is a project property for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to not have a group of files within a project inspected, you can filter these files out so they are not inspected by creating a **file filter**

The file filter uses regex to determine what files to exclude.  The regex operates on the complete file name - because of this, you could also exclude whole folders.  In this case you could exclude the whole package if you wished.

If you google around a bit - you could probably find some Checkstyle Configuration Propertie files that have examples of what you're looking for.  I would suggest after you do so - save it as a bit of a template so you can refer to it in future situations