# Exclude checkstyle FileLength module/check for specific files?

Tags: checkstyle, exclude-constraint

When I run checkstyle through pre-commit, it gives the following warnings:

```bash
checkstyle...............................................................Failed
- hook id: checkstyle
- exit code: 4

Starting audit...
[ERROR] /some_path/AnotherSomeFile.java:1: File length is 1,950 lines (max allowed is 1,000). [FileLength]
[ERROR] /some_path/someFile.java:1: File length is 1,676 lines (max allowed is 1,000). [FileLength]
Audit done.
Checkstyle ends with 4 errors.
```

I have disabled the other checkstyle errors for those files by including the line:

```
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
```

inside the   `<module name="TreeWalker">` module (and including `// CHECKSTYLE:OFF` at the top of each file that I want to ignore with checkstyle. (As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019054/7437143) answer. However, the

```
<module name="FileLength">
            <property name="max" value="1000"/>
        </module>
```

check needs to be above/outside of the `TreeWalker` module inside the `checkstyle.xml` file. That means the `SuppressionCommentFilter` module does not apply to the `FileLength` module inside the `checkstyle.xml`.

### Attempts

- I tried moving the `FileLength` module inside the `TreeWalker` module, and that is not allowed.
- I tried copying the `SuppressionCommentFilter` into the parent of `TreeWalker`/at the same level/below the `FileLength` check module, and that is not allowed.

### Question

How can I exclude the `FileLength` module for 4 files at `src/some_path/file_one.java`, `src/some_path/file_two.java` etc. inside the `checkstyle.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SuppressionFilter](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/filters/suppressionfilter.html) to exclude the `FileLength` check for specific files. The suppression filter accepts a `suppressions.xml` config file. The files to be excluded will be supplied as a regex within this config file. The config files would look something like below:

**checkstyle.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
  <module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="suppressions.xml"/>
    <property name="optional" value="false"/>
  </module>
  <module name="FileLength">
    <property name="max" value="1000"/>
  </module>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

**suppressions.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
  "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.2//EN"
  "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2.dtd">

<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="FileLengthCheck" files="file_one.*|file_two.*"/>
</suppressions>
```

Comment: Magnificent, I have verified your answer works, thank you!